# ValueError: shapes (882,14) and (15,) not aligned: 14 (dim 1) != 15 (dim 0)

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

Unable to solve the error, please advise
code:

## Training the model

```
X_train_stepwise = X_train[['Schooling', 'Adult Mortality', 
'HIV/AIDS', 'Diphtheria', 'BMI', 'Income composition of resources', 
'Status', 'percentage expenditure', 'Polio', 'Measles', 'Hepatitis B', 
'under-five deaths', 'infant deaths', 'thinness  1-19 years']]
```

Adding a constant variable and Build a second fitted model

```
X_train_stepwise = sm.add_constant(X_train_stepwise)
lm_stepwise = sm.OLS(y_train, X_train_stepwise).fit()
```

Summary of linear model

```
 print(lm_stepwise.summary())
```

Predicting the price of training set.

```
X_test_stepwise = X_test[['Schooling', 'Adult Mortality', 'HIV/AIDS', 
   'Diphtheria', 'BMI', 'Income composition of resources', 'Status', 
   'percentage expenditure', 'Polio', 'Measles', 'Hepatitis B', 
   'under-five deaths', 'infant deaths', 'thinness  1-19 years']]

# X_test_sm = sm.add_constant(X_test_stepwise)


actual = y_test["Life expectancy"]


prediction = lm_stepwise.predict(X_test_stepwise)
```

Comment: This error will occur mainly is because the two matrix does not fit the dimensions for Matrix Multiplication. I suggest you to do some research on Matrix Multiplication. The columns for the first Matrix must need to be as same as the rows for the second Matrix in order to do the Matrix Multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

In matrix multiplication the second matrix should have a number of rows that is equal to the number of columns in the first one. Execute each columns individually in a notebook to check which matrices are causing the problem.